# DNN, targets[3] is out of range error

Tags: python, tensorflow, kaggle

I am currently building a triple-layered DNN to solve the Titanic Dataset problem. While building the model, I get the following error:

```
targets[3] is out of range
```

My code can be accessed through my github account: https://github.com/isaac-altair/Titanic-Dataset/blob/master/Titanic%2BProject.ipynb

Thank you

Comment: Please close this question as the problem has been solved (I would not know exactly what I did, but my code works). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.7/api_docs/python/tf/nn/in_top_k) `tf.nn.in_top_k` expects tensor of type `float32` with shape `batch_size x classes`. In you case you have 2 classes, so `predictions` tensor should have shape `batch_size x 2`.

Comment: I tried writing batches * 2, "X_batch, y_batch = random_batch(X_train, np.array(train_labels), batch_size * 2)", but it still gives me an error.